# PHP link two search bars to different results

Tags: php, image, search, display

I want to have two identical search bars but which lead to different results. However the problem and that the result of a search is then displayed during a search on the second search bar, the second result erases the first. I do not understand how this can be possible, if there is a way to display the results at the same time on the same page, I am interested. thank you in advance

Code one

```
<?php
    include_once ('searcht.php');
    ?></br><?php
    include_once ('searche.php');
?>
```

Code for search bar one "searcht.php"

```
<div class="t"><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Search</label>
<input type="text" name="searcht">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
   $hostt = "localhost";
   $db_namet = "photos";
   $usernamet = "root";
   $passwordt = "";

   try{
    $cont = new PDO("mysql:host={$hostt};dbname={$db_namet}", $usernamet, $passwordt);
   }

   catch(PDOException $exceptiont){
   //to handle connection error
   echo "Connection error: " . $exceptiont->getMessage();
   }

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $strt = $_POST["searcht"];
  $stht = $cont->prepare("SELECT image, image_nom, image_text FROM images WHERE image_nom = 
 '$strt'");


$stht->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
$stht -> execute();



if($rowt = $stht->fetch())
{
    
    ?>
    <br><br><br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Fiche</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='image'><?php print "<img src='images/$rowt->image'>";?></td>
            <td><?php print $rowt->image_nom; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $rowt->image_text;?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php 
 }else{
    echo "Aucune personne s'apelle comme çà";
}
}
  
?>
</div>
```

Code for search bar two "searche.php"

```
<div class="e"><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Search</label>
<input type="text" name="searche">
<input type="submit" name="submite">    
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

  $host = "localhost";
  $db_name = "photos";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";

  try{
   $cone = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db_name}", $username, $password);
  }

  catch(PDOException $exception){
   //to handle connection error
   echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
   }

   if (isset($_POST["submite"])) {
     $stre = $_POST["searche"];
     $sthe = $cone->prepare("SELECT image, image_nom, image_text FROM images WHERE image_nom = 
     '$stre'");

     $sthe->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
     $sthe -> execute();



    if($rowe = $sthe->fetch())
    {
    
    ?>
    <br><br><br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Fiche</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rowe->image_text;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowe->image_nom; ?></td>
            <td class='image'><?php echo "<img src='images/$rowe->image'>";?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
 <?php 
 }else{
    echo "Aucune personne s'apelle comme çà";
 }
 }
  
 ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: sorry i didn't understand how to display the code correctly

Comment: You can check it here: [ask]

Comment: You are not telling the input to be populated with the value of the submitted data

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what was the difference in `searcht.php` and `searche.php`. Anyway, you can just use two buttons to separate the request. And, you can use `if(isset($_POST['submitt']))` for the `submitt` submission and `if(isset($_POST['submite']))` for the `submite` submission.

```
<div class="t">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Search</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submitt" value="Submit T">
        <input type="submit" name="submite" value="Submit E">
    </form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submitt"])) {

        $hostt = "localhost";
        $db_namet = "photos";
        $usernamet = "root";
        $passwordt = "";
        try{
            $cont = new PDO("mysql:host={$hostt};dbname={$db_namet}", $usernamet, $passwordt);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exceptiont){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exceptiont->getMessage();
        }
    
        $stht = $cont->prepare("SELECT image, image_nom, image_text FROM images WHERE image_nom = '$strt'");
        $stht->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
        $stht->execute();    

    } else if(isset($_POST["submite"])) {
        
        $hostt = "localhost";
        $db_namet = "photos";
        $usernamet = "root";
        $passwordt = "";
        try{
            $cont = new PDO("mysql:host={$hostt};dbname={$db_namet}", $usernamet, $passwordt);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exceptiont){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exceptiont->getMessage();
        }
    
        $stht = $cont->prepare("SELECT image, image_nom, image_text FROM images WHERE image_nom = '$strt'");
        $stht->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
        $stht->execute();    
        
    }
    if(isset($stht)){
        if($row = $stht->fetch()){
            ?>
            <br><br><br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Fiche</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='image'><?php print "<img src='images/$row->image'>";?></td>
                    <td><?php print $row->image_nom; ?></td>
                    <td><?php print $row->image_text;?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php 
        }else{
            echo "Aucune personne s'apelle comme çà";
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```